# AMCharts 5 multiple data series showing on same chart

Tags: amcharts5

Whilst I can find this in AMCharts 4 documentation I cannot find out how to do this in AMCharts 5.
Quite simply I want a stacked column chart whilst I also wish to show a line chart for a different set of data values.  In the data example below, the values for the continents add up for each year in stacked column, the "budget" is to be plotted as a line chart on the same graph.  Sounds simple enough, but I am really struggling to get it to appear

```
am5.ready(function () {
    
    var root = am5.Root.new(cssId);
    root.setThemes([
        am5themes_Animated.new(root)
    ]);


    // Create chart        
    var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
        panX: false,
        panY: false,
        wheelX: "panX",
        wheelY: "zoomX",
        layout: root.verticalLayout
    }));          

    var data = [{
        "year": "2021",
        "europe": 2.5,
        "namerica": 2.5,
        "asia": 2.1,
        "lamerica": 1,
        "meast": 0.8,
        "africa": 0.4,
        "budget": 155
    }, {
        "year": "2022",
        "europe": 2.6,
        "namerica": 2.7,
        "asia": 2.2,
        "lamerica": 0.5,
        "meast": 0.4,
        "africa": 0.3,
        "budget": 100
    }, {
        "year": "2023",
        "europe": 2.8,
        "namerica": 2.9,
        "asia": 2.4,
        "lamerica": 0.3,
        "meast": 0.9,
        "africa": 0.5,
        "budget": 120
    }]

     // Create axes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
    var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        categoryField: "year",
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
    }));

    var xAxis2 = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
        categoryField: "Rate",
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, {}),
        tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
    }));


    xAxis.data.setAll(data);
    xAxis2.data.setAll(data2);
           

    var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
        min: 0,
        calculateTotals: false,
        renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
    }));

    // Add legend
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/legend-xy-series/
    var legend = chart.children.push(am5.Legend.new(root, {
        centerX: am5.p50,
        x: am5.p50
    }));

    // Add series
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
    function makeSeries(name, fieldName) {
        var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
            name: name,
            stacked: true,
            maskBullets: false,
            xAxis: xAxis,
            yAxis: yAxis,               
            valueYField: fieldName,
            categoryXField: "year"
        }));

        var series0 = chart.series.push(am5xy.LineSeries.new(root, {
            xAxis: xAxis,
            yAxis: yAxis,
            valueYField: "year",
            categoryXField: "budget"
        }));

        chart.get("colors").set("colors", [
            am5.color("#d8764b"),
            am5.color("#ca4c6a"),
            am5.color("#188a89"),
            am5.color("#189bd0"),
            am5.color("#241047")
        ]);

        series.columns.template.setAll({
            tooltipText: "{name}, {categoryX}: {valueY}",
            tooltipY: am5.percent(10)
        });
        series.data.setAll(data);

        series0.LineSeries.template.setAll({
            tooltipText: "{name}, {categoryX}: {valueY}",
            tooltipY: am5.percent(10)
        });
        series0.data.setAll(data);


        series.bullets.push(function () {
            return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
                locationY: 1,
                sprite: am5.Label.new(root, {
                    text: "{valueYTotal}",
                    fill: am5.color(0x000000),
                    centerY: am5.p100,
                    centerX: am5.p50,
                    populateText: true
                })
            });
        });
                  
        series.appear();
        series0.appear();

        series.bullets.push(function () {
            return am5.Bullet.new(root, {
                sprite: am5.Label.new(root, {
                    text: "{valueY}",
                    fill: root.interfaceColors.get("alternativeText"),
                    centerY: am5.p50,
                    centerX: am5.p50,
                    populateText: true
                })
            });
        });

        legend.data.push(series);
    }

    makeSeries("Europe", "europe");
    makeSeries("North America", "namerica");
    makeSeries("Asia", "asia");
    makeSeries("Latin America", "lamerica");
    makeSeries("Middle East", "meast");
    makeSeries("Africa", "africa");
    
    chart.appear(1000, 100);

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by just adding one col like this:

```
var data = [{
  "year": "2022",
  "value1": 10,
  "value2": 2.5,
  "value3": 1
}]
```

Later you will have to change text and values to match it. I really dont know why they just threw graphics like the cilynder when updating from amcharts4 to 5